# On a necessary condition for being a prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, lattice-orders

All rings below are commutative with unity.

If $P$ is a prime ideal in a ring $R$, then it has the following property:

(*) For every ideal $I,J$ of $R$, $I \cap J \subseteq P \implies I \subseteq P$ or $J\subseteq P$.

However, condition (*) doesn't necessarily imply that $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$; in fact, that is not even true in a PID like $\mathbb Z$.

So my questions are

(1) Does some extra assumption along with (*) imply that $P$ is a prime ideal?

(2) Can we classify all those rings where condition (*) is equivalent to being a prime ideal?

Comment: Why doesn't $(*)$ imply $P$ to be a prime ideal? In particular, how is it not true for $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Pig: Let $p \in \mathbb Z$ be a prime. For any $0\ne a,b\in \mathbb Z$, $(a)\cap(b)=(\ l.c.m. (a,b) )$. So if $(a) \cap (b) \subseteq (p^2)$, then $p^2|\ l.c.m. (a,b)$ so either $p^2|a$ or $p^2|b$, so $(a) \subseteq (p^2)$ or $(b)\subseteq (p^2)$. Thus $(p^2)$ has property (*) but $(p^2)$ is not a prime ideal ...

Comment: The condition that $P$ is radical is sufficient. Indeed if $x,y\in R$ satisfy $xy \in P$, then every $z \in \left(x\right) \cap \left(y\right)$ satisfies $z^2 \in \left(xy\right) \subseteq P$, thus $z \in P$ (if $P$ is radical), and this shows that $\left(x\right) \cap \left(y\right) \subseteq P$; then your assumption (*) yields that $x \in P$ or $y \in P$.

Comment: I am wondering if (*) describes primary ideals. Too bad I don't know any other examples than $\left(p^n\right)$ right off my hat...

Comment: @darijgrinberg: thanks for your comment on the radical ideal ... yeah primary would be a reasonable guess, but I'm not that sure ...

Comment: The true definition is, if $P$ is a prime ideal:
$ \text{ For every ideal } I,J \text{ of } R, \text{ if } I\cdot J \subset P \implies I \subset P \text{ or} J \subset P $
And note that $ I\cdot J \neq I\cap J$

Comment: @M.Di I suspect the poster knows that.

Comment: @M.Di: we all know that ... the very point of this post is to explore a weaker condition ...

Comment: @darij grinberg If the ideals are totally ordered (e.g. valuation ring), then the property becomes completely vacuous. So this certainly is not describing primary ideals.

Comment: @Badam Baplan: you're absolutely right (never mind my previous stupid comment, now deleted) ... that's a very good point you make